# dist() function in R outputs

Tags: r, matrix, output, distance

I am curious about dist() output results that I get. More specifically, if I try

```
a=matrix(rnorm(1:100),nrow=10)
dist(a)
```

ok, I get what I expected

```
          1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9
2  3.700582                                                                        
3  3.793826 4.391523                                                               
4  3.063703 5.386797 5.494179                                                      
5  3.205545 4.464493 3.839944 3.763671                                             
6  3.868796 4.954696 3.340530 5.165389 3.589912                                    
7  3.906698 3.971069 3.405455 5.403859 4.284414 4.774963                           
8  2.620238 4.479064 5.403749 3.128820 4.237437 5.272889 5.551908                  
9  3.645784 4.586749 5.508289 3.333739 4.318391 6.113694 4.796519 3.641355         
10 2.292591 4.152536 4.869231 3.445773 3.557222 3.992109 4.061925 3.740496 4.225799
```

Nice, but: when I have a larger matrix

```
dim(Large_m)
[1] 978 235
```

I try

```
a=dist(Large_m)
```

I do not get a matrix, rather a 'Large dist' object as Rstudio says.

Is it correct if I use it with `as.matrix` ?

```
b=as.matrix(a)
```

b as I checked is indeed a matrix and seems like the distance matrix.

Also, I really need the row names in the distance matrix, not just numbers but in this way (working with `as.matrix`) I can't get it.

Seems I'm missing something, can't be so complicated to just create a distance matrix in R.

Comment: I dunno what seems complicated there: `a=dist(matrix(rnorm(1:(978*325)),ncol=325));is.matrix(a)`

Comment: @Colonel Beauvel  This gets me [1] FALSE. I need to have an output that is a matrix with the names included.

Comment: what version of R do you have?

Comment: I'm using R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31) and working on RStudio Version 0.98.1102 if it's relevant.

Comment: hum, how do you detect the 'Large dist' obejct? by using `typeof`?

Comment: I tried to post a pic but my 'reputation' is not enough! I get the 'Large dist' in the environment tab of Rstudio. with typeof I get "double".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an explicit example of what was suggested in the comments by @ColonelBeauvel. (I think there was some confusion due to a typo in a comment: as.matrix() vs is.matrix()...)

Large random matrix:

```
cols <- 325
rows <- 978

m <- matrix(rnorm(1:(rows*cols)), ncol=cols)
```

Let's give rows and columns a name:

```
rownames(m) <- paste0("r", 1:rows)
colnames(m) <- paste0("c", 1:cols)
```

Calculate distance object with `dist` then turn it into a regular matrix with `as.matrix` (as suggested by Colonel Beauvel):

```
d <- dist(m)
dm <- as.matrix(d)
```

Check the types:

```
class(d)
[1] "dist"
class(dm)
[1] "matrix"
```

Names are preserved in the distance matrix dm. Here's a small piece of it:

```
dm[1:3,1:3]
         r1       r2       r3
r1  0.00000 24.64059 26.63301
r2 24.64059  0.00000 25.69792
r3 26.63301 25.69792  0.00000
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks both WhiteViking and @ColonolBeauvel. I had to understand what exactly the object dist means and the connection with the actual calculations. Now I think it's clear to me.